# Using case when vs. joining on a mapping

Tags: mysql, mapping, left-join, case

I want to do a simple mapping of a column e.g. a = apple, b = banana, c = cucumber.

I could either

```
Select 
  consumer,
  case when letter = 'a' then 'apple'
  case when letter = 'b' then 'banana'
  case when letter = 'c' then 'cucumber' end as edible    
From letter_table
```

Or

```
Select
  consumer,
  mapping.edible
from letter_table left join mapping
  on letter_table.letter = mapping.letter
```

Is one method generally preferable? If so why?

My main concern would be speed. With large mappings it would be cumbersome to write out the case statement and I would typically create the mapping table and use the join. With small tables I would typically write out the case statement. Assume the columns used are indexed, and the user has read write privileges.

Comment: First statement will access the table only once and save time spent on joins

Comment: I assume `apple` etc. should be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a proven performance issue, I would always go with second option, as it allows you to add new mappings and it provides an authoritative reference point instead of relying on each query to get it right. I would actually take it a step further and drop the redundant letter in favor of a foreign key pointing to the mapping table.

Another option worth considering is using an [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html) datatype to store the full value without the extra disk space. One downside is that adding new types requires an `ALTER TABLE`, which can be expensive for large tables.

Comment: agree with almost everything except enum. enum is evil

Comment: @e4c5 Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The former method hard-codes the mapping into your code; while the latter method allows the map to change over time without having to touch the code.

In our environment we use both approach -- we use the former method for static mapping, and use the latter if the mapping may change over time.